# save a web view content as pdf file

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf, webview

Notice: I working with swift 4 for osx.
I would like to generate a pdf file from a WebView.

At the moment my WebView load a html-string and show this successfully.
If I press a button, the print panel will open and is ready to print my WebView content in the correct format.

This is my print code:

```
var webView = WebView()
var htmlString = "MY HTML STRING"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    webView.mainFrame.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
}

func webView(_ sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadFor frame: WebFrame!) {

    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
    printInfo.paperSize = NSMakeSize(595.22, 841.85)
    printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
    printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
    printInfo.orientation = .portrait
    printInfo.topMargin = 50
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 50
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0
    printInfo.verticalPagination = .autoPagination
    printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fitPagination
    //webView.mainFrame.frameView.printOperation(with: printInfo).run()

    let printOp: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)
    printOp.showsPrintPanel = true
    printOp.showsProgressPanel = false
    printOp.run() 
}
```

[image]

Now I would like to have another button, which save the content directly as a pdf file.

I tried this:

```
let pdfData = webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.dataWithPDF(inside: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.frame)
let document = PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("myPDF.pdf")
document?.write(to: fileURL)
```

But the result of my pdf looks horrible:

[image]

Have anybody an idea?

**UPDATE**
This is a part of my web view result:

[image]

and that is the result of my print preview / pdf file /the color is missing, but now everywhere. the "logo"(picture) will show with color:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `dataWithPDF` uses the view's current frame to decide how wide the generated PDF should be. Since your `WebView`'s frame in your app is probably skinnier than an 8.5/11" page, you're getting a PDF that is inadequately wide. You *could* adjust the `WebView`'s frame to the right size, make the PDF, and then adjust it back, or you could create a new `WebView`, render it offscreen, set it to the appropriate size, and create the PDF. That's a bit of a pain in the backside, though. Wouldn't it be great if there were a way to programatically do what the "PDF" button in the Print dialog does, since the print system handles all this stuff for you automatically?

Well, turns out you can! But you have to dive into the poorly-documented world of Core Printing.

```
func makePDF(at url: URL, for webView: WebView, printInfo: NSPrintInfo) throws {
    webView.preferences.shouldPrintBackgrounds = true

    guard let printOp = webView.mainFrame.frameView.printOperation(with: printInfo) else {
        throw MyPrintError.couldntGetPrintOperation // or something like this
    }

    let session = PMPrintSession(printOp.printInfo.pmPrintSession())
    let settings = PMPrintSettings(printOp.printInfo.pmPrintSettings())

    if PMSessionSetDestination(session,
                               settings,
                               PMDestinationType(kPMDestinationFile),
                               kPMDocumentFormatPDF as CFString,
                               url as CFURL) != noErr {
        throw MyPrintError.couldntSetDestination // or something like this
    }

    printOp.showsPrintPanel = false
    printOp.run()
}
```

The key is the `PMSessionSetDestination` call, which allows us to configure the print session to print to a PDF instead of to an actual printer. Then we just tell `NSPrintOperation` not to show the print panel, run the operation, and presto! PDF printed.

Comment: that is brilliant and works good !! and i will you give your 100 reputation now. but there is one little thing which not works perfectly yet. how can i set the size of a din A4 page for the the pdf. the result doesn't looks like a original Din A4 size. can you help me with that, too?

Comment: Adjusting the settings in the `NSPrintInfo` ought to be able to get you the paper size you want. I tried it with the `NSPrintInfo` you provided in your question and it looked like A4 size to me.

Comment: yes your are right, my fault. but somethings is wrong with the "quality". please look at my first post, I added two pictures

Comment: Does the web page have a separate print style sheet? That would explain why it prints differently.

Comment: no, i do not use a separated print style sheet. this was my first idea, too :/

Comment: Does it look the same way if you do a normal Print and click the Preview button?

Comment: Looked into this a bit. Turns out that `WebView` won't print background colors or images by default, which makes sense since in most cases, printing the backgrounds would waste a lot of toner and probably make the text less readable. This can be turned off, though, in `WebView`'s `.preferences`. I've updated the answer. I also found out that `WebFrameView` has its own method to create a print operation, and I figured that would be better than making one from scratch, so I changed that part of the answer too.